# Point root domain to Heroku without IP and CNAME (Rails)

Tags: apache, heroku, dns, configuration-files, domain-name

My domain provider uses only A records with IP addresses for **root domains** and Heroku doesn't accept that. I was told to use an .htaccess file to point `mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com` which is linked with a CNAME record and secured with SSL on Heroku.

I have no idea how this works and according to the apache doc, using an htaccess file reduces the HTTP server's speed. Instead I should write the configuration inside a `<Directory>` block in the main server configuration file.

Has anyone any recommendations? If I have to use the `<Directory>` block, where can I find the main server config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Heroku add-on like PointDNS, where you can point your root domain to Heroku via PointDNS Nameservers.

For steps, follow: https://www.mirrorcommunications.com/blog/how-to-correctly-point-your-domain-to-heroku, Option #1